# Why am I getting wkhtmltopdf IO Error when invoking via python-pdfkit?

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm trying to upgrade my `wkhtmltopdf` package to `0.12.2.1` and not having any luck.

- It did work before the update. The reason I'm trying to update is to
  fix the *splitting* of content between PDF pages.
- I'm running - Ubuntu 64x  - Trusty
- I'm using via python-pdfkit.
- I started with getting the newest release of `wkhtmltopdf` http://sourceforge.net/projects/wkhtmltopdf/files/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb/download?use_mirror=hivelocity

Below is what I've done/tried so far.  Has anyone had any luck updating their setup?  Or any pointers would be greatly helpful!  Thanks!

Out of the box I got `Configuration Error` I hard coded to simply get past this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import sys

class Configuration(object):
    def __init__(self, wkhtmltopdf='', meta_tag_prefix='pdfkit-'):
        self.meta_tag_prefix = meta_tag_prefix

        self.wkhtmltopdf = wkhtmltopdf

        if not self.wkhtmltopdf:
            if sys.platform == 'win32':
                self.wkhtmltopdf = subprocess.Popen(                    ['where', 'wkhtmltopdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
            else:
                self.wkhtmltopdf = subprocess.Popen( ['which', 'wkhtmltopdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()

        try:
            #with open(self.wkhtmltopdf) as f:
           with open("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf") as f:
                pass
        except IOError:
            raise IOError('No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "%s"\n'
                          'If this file exists please check that this process can '
                          'read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - '
                          'https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf' % self.wkhtmltopdf)
```

Now I'm getting this error and do not know how to proceed.  I tried adding `shell=True` to the Popen above but that didn't work either.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rq/worker.py", line 543, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rq/job.py", line 490, in perform
    self._result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/worker-1/Desktop/Dropbox/changeaddress/facts/jobs.py", line 864, in job_sharepdfs
    mymovepdf_link = build_mymovepdf(account_uuid, addresschange_uuid)
  File "/home/worker-1/Desktop/Dropbox/changeaddress/facts/jobs.py", line 608, in build_mymovepdf
    s3file = pdfkit.from_string( output.getvalue() , False )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfkit/api.py", line 68, in from_string
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 93, in to_pdf
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `configuration` (path) of your `wkhtmltopdf` library.

I have created a basic helper function like below,

```
import os
import pdfkit

WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'

def generate_pdf(html, static_path,  _path):
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH)
    _status = pdfkit.from_string(
        html,
        os.path.join(static_path, _path),
        configuration=config,
        options={
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'margin-top': '0',
            'margin-right': '0',
            'margin-left': '0',
            'margin-bottom': '0',
            'zoom': '1.2',
            'encoding': "UTF-8",
        })
    return _path if _status else ''
```

**Use:**

```
html = "<h1>Hello World !!!</h1>"
static_path = "/static/"
file_path = "pdfs/out.pdf"
generate_pdf(html, static_path, file_path)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution (installing `wkhtmltopdf`):

```
wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
sudo mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: Please be informed that http://download.gna.org is closed now. So if you want to download lates binaries visit [this link](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

Comment: Any solution Mac M1 Chip ??